# C# WP8.1 register touch (press AND release)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

Can't figure this out.

I would like to catch both the inital touch from a users finger and also the release. (Hence, not Click or Tap event).

Just like the MouseDown and MouseUp.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following properties

```
ManipulationStarted
ManipulationCompleted
ManipulationDelta
```

Comment: Thanks, how to use on button? Neither of them seems to fire on a button element.

Comment: Oh, was missing ManipulationMode. Thanks :)